# Notice: Undefined variable: row in. Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

El codigo me tira

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in. Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in,

Por lo que veo ya definí el `$row`, ¿Qué puede estar pasando que me tira el error?

Preciso de su ayuda para poder hacer que funcione y los `input` me mestre los datos del usuario.

El problem esta en la siguiente función. ¿Qué cosas estan mal para poder arreglar y hacer que funcione el siguiente código?. La base de datos esta en load.php.

```
<?php
        require_once '../includes/load.php';
        if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])) {
            $iduser = $_SESSION['usuario_id'];
            $sqls = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_id ".$_GET['usuario_id'];
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqls);
            $stmt->bindParam(':usuario_id', $iduser, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
            } else {
                $row["usuario_id"]="";
                $row["nombre"]="";
                $row["mail"]="";
                $row["usuario"]="";
                $row["clave"]="";
                $row["rol"]="";
                $row["estado"]="";
            }
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['usuario_id'])) {
            $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        
            $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET mail='$mail' WHERE usuario_id='$iduser'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            echo "Profile updated successfully";
        }
        ?>
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="modaleditarUsuario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header headerRegister">
                        <h5 class="modal-title fs-5" id="tituloModalEditar">Editar Usuario</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="formEditarUsuario" name="formEditarUsuario" action="/instituto/Includes/sql.php"
                            method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="idusuarioeditar" id="idusuarioeditar" value="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="control-label">Nombre:</label>
              
        
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreeditar" id="nombreeditar" value="<?= htmlspecialchars(isset($row['nombre'])?$row['nombre']:'') ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="control-label">Mail:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maileditar" id="maileditar" value="<?php echo $row['mail']; ?>" required>
        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="control-label">Contraseña:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="claveeditar" id="claveeditar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="listRol">Rol</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="listRoleditar" id="listRoleditar" value="<?= $row['rol']; ?>">
                                    <option value="1">Administrador</option>
                                    <option value="2">Profesor</option>
                                    <option value="3">Alumno</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="listEstado">Estado</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="listEstadoeditar" id="listEstadoeditar" value="<?= $row['estado']; ?>">
                                    <option value="1">Activo</option>
                                    <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                <button id="btnActionEditarForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-open-modal" type="submit">
                                    <span id="btnEditartext">Guardar</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Buen día, `$row` está definida únicamente adentro del `if` si la condición del `if` es falsa entonces esa variable nunca sería definida, esa es la razón del error. Define `$row` antes del `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un signo de asignación en esta consulta:

```
$sqls = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_id ".$_GET['usuario_id'];
```

Adicionalmente, no es recomendable usar directamente las variables $_GET, $_POST, etc. sin sanitizar. Es recomendable hacer:

```
$id_usuario = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'usuario_id');
```

y utilizar la variable $id_usuario en lugar de $_GET['usuario_id']. Recuerda que dentro de las comillas dobles el código PHP se expande, entonces puedes escribir tu consulta como:

```
$id_usuario = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'usuario_id');
$sqls = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_id = $id_usuario";
```